# Use of python close command (LPTHW ex 17 extra credit)

Tags: python

Looking at line 8 and the last line (marked with comments), in terms of best practice, do I need to close the "from_file"?  I tried closing as below on the last line (from_file.close()) but this generates an error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'close'
```

Changing the code to indata.close() generates the same error.  (And also makes no sense because indata is a variable, not a file.)

Was the from_file automatically closed after its contents were assigned to the indata variable?  Or if not, how can I manually close it?

Thanks!

```
from sys import argv
from os.path import exists

script, from_file, to_file = argv

print "Copying from %s to %s" % (from_file, to_file)

# the next line is the issue

indata = open(from_file).read()

print "The input file is %d bytes long" % len(indata)

print "Does the output file exist? %r" % exists(to_file)
print "Ready, hit RETURN to continue, CTRL-C to abort."
raw_input()

output = open(to_file, 'w')
output.write(indata)

print "All right, all done."

output.close()

#this line is the issue
from_file.close()
```

Comment: can you do a `print type(from_file)` and see if indeed it is a `<type 'file'>`? The error message suggests it's receiving a string as its datatype. This will of course affect the result of `indata` and its associated error. Basically, inspect the assignments of each datatype after the line `script, from_file, to_file = argv`

Comment: Why are you trying to close a string?